# TFVC "Undo Unchanged" Error in Ubuntu pipeline

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tfs, azure-pipelines, tfvc

I'm trying to run an "undo unchanged" command in a Linux TFVC pipeline.

The commands are run from a bash script:

```
tf workspaces -login:${credentials} -collection:${collectionURL}
tf checkout * -recursive -login:${credentials}
tf uu * -recursive -login:${credentials} -collection:${collectionURL}
tf checkin * -recursive -comment:${comment} -login:${credentials} -noprompt
```

The problem is that the third command fails:

```
tf uu * -recursive -login:${credentials} -collection:${collectionURL}
```

With the error:

```
An error occured: There is no working folder mapping for '/home/user/tfsAgent/_work/1/s/folder_name'
```

I understand that the problem is that I don't have a direct mapping to the directory 'folder_name': Instead, I have mappings to several of its subdirectories.

There is no specific path in the source-control which I can map directly to the directory 'folder_name'. 
Is there no workaround for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Inbar, any update on this issue? According to the error, you need to use tf workspace command to the target folder , cd inside it and run tf uu command. Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Hey, sorry for the late answer - you were were right, this does work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were trying to use `tf uu` command to undo checkout of unmodified files in a batch file.

This command need to be called in a workspace, the folder should have a mapping relationship.

> An error occured: There is no working folder mapping for
>   '/home/user/tfsAgent/_work/1/s/folder_name'

According to the error, you need to use `tf workspace` command to the target folder , cd inside it and run tf uu command.

Comment: Hey Patrick, he's got to use Team Explorer Everywhere (Eclipse plugin) because he's on linux, this does support "uu" I think.

Comment: @Inbar You may need to use TF workspace to the target folder and CD inside it, from there you can do the UU command.